# Is there a rule for Rashi's French transliterations (Laaz)?

Tags: translation, rashi, language, transliteration

Rashi frequently uses French words in his explanation to Chumash or the Gemara. However, he doesn't write it in the original language, but he writes it in a "transliteration" of French in Hebrew lettering.

Are there any rules to "transliterate" it back to French?

Comment: Inspired by [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15021&pgnum=1558) question as to how to pronounce the Shin in La'az.

Comment: I wish I could +100 this. I've been wondering this for years!

Comment: @HodofHod Too bad there are no bounties for questions...

Comment: @yydl I know, right? Give it a week.

Comment: Wow, talk about a blast from the past. The הת' אלכסנדר הפנהיימר who wrote that question - is me!

Comment: FYI, this "French" you speak of is not French as spoken now, and many words are different. I'll even go so far as to say that you may assume words will be different. In _Rashi_'s time they still spoke what we now call Old French (from which, incidentally, many English words derive, due to the Norman Conquest).

Comment: @Alex I'm tempted, a la http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts , to create some sort of contest looking for references to you in the literature. :)

Comment: @IsaacMoses http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2825813#2825813

Comment: @Alex, side question - what did you mean by your third suggested explanation in that question: "שכוונתם היתה כנ״ל: בימיהם לא חילקו במבטא בין
שי״ן ימנית לסמ״ך (כדרך ה״ליטוואקים")״

Comment: @SethJ: stereotypically, Litvaks pronounce shin and samech the same (actually, as a phoneme halfway between both of them). Though I don't know whether there are any present-day speakers who do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Dayan Gukovitzky's [Targum HaLaaz](http://www.worldcat.org/title/sefer-targum-ha-laaz-al-ha-shas-ve-al-hamishah-humshe-torah/oclc/26126373&referer=brief_results) has a transliteration guide. It seems that Rashi did have a specific set of rules for doing this.

Comment: As does [Otzar Laazei Rashi, pp. 12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48058&st=&pgnum=9)-13.

Comment: @Alex, why not a separate answer?

Comment: @HodofHod: I think both Dayan Gukovitzky's and Catane's lists both go back to a common source, so they're not really separate answers.

Comment: @Alex aha......

Comment: @Alex, What source is that?

Comment: @SethJ: a 1929 work by David Shimon Blondheim and Arsene Darmesteter, *Les gloses françaises dans le commentaire talmudique de Raschi*. Catane mentions it at the beginning of his introduction.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for this and your response on my other comment. Does Dayan Gukovitzky give this same source?

Comment: @SethJ: I last saw his sefer years ago (it doesn't seem to be available online), and I think he did give this same reference, but I don't remember for sure.