# What is the most effective way to translate non-Hebrew translations found in Rabbinic literature?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, translation, language, transliteration

Non-Hebrew translations are often included by our Sages when attempting to clarify words or concepts.

There are myriad examples in RaSh"I ([Shemot 5:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9866#v=7&showrashi=true)) and Hizquni ([Wayiqra 11:16](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/parshanut/chizkuni/3.pdf)). For relatively later writings, Shulhan `Arukh is also chock-full of these ([OH 10:8](https://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_1/0030_Siman_10_Seif_7b-11a.pdf), [OH 10:12](https://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_1/0031_Siman_10_Seif_11b-Siman_11_Seif_1a.pdf), [OH 254:5](https://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_3/0644_Siman_254_Seif_2b-5a.pdf)).

Given the ambiguous *niqqud* of these translations (I'm not aware of any Rabbinic literature originally written with niqqud), what is the most effective way of deciphering of our Sages' writings?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92486/2091

Comment: A lot of these things are cultural and wouldn't be obvious to us even if they were written in Hebrew.  I'm thinking of the thing ladies would wear to ride horses as described by Rashi in Tetzaveh.  He does use a French word, but the description makes sense without it, and is still not that helpful because we don't live in medieval France.  (His description of the eifod is fine without it, but we still miss that piece.).  I doubt that knowing what "portzint" (?) meant would make it any clearer.

Comment: On the other hand, distinguishing between the two words Rashi uses for נרות is very helpful.  (One is לוצי"ש, I don't remember the other)

Comment: @Heshy I suppose Rashi's idea was to make his point more understandable to his compatriots of his age. Obviously I will understand everything far quicker in my mother tounge. But Rashi uses French words almost exclusively _in addition_ to his explanations. Therefore, in my view, for us, it has a limited relevance (on the other side it's a gold mine for linguists).

Comment: @Kazibácsi I disagree. Understanding the nuances between different (French) words could help us better understand the original Hebrew.

Comment: @Lee It's difficult to get nuances out of any translation, whether it's into English, Hebrew, or Navajo.  If you want to learn medieval French, good for you, but I'm not convinced the years of study are worth the small insights you'll get into Rashi and other rishonim.  There are other things to learn that would help more in Torah. (e.g. botany for kilayim maasros etc.). I'd love to learn everything myself, but Hashem gave us a limited time to accomplish what we can.

Comment: @Lee Cost vs. benefit as Heshy said. In your own example he describes what does he mean. If I Google [how bricks are made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick#Mudbrick) or ask an expert, I will instantly know what did he refer to, while playing with medieval French words is way more difficult ([another classic example](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8220/jewish/Chapter-25.htm#v=25&showrashi=true)). I'm quite convinced that he used it to help his French contemporaries...

Comment: As an aside, for Rashi there is the sefer mentioned in the answer to this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/is-there-a-rule-for-rashis-french-transliterations-laaz